# Regex: How to find a phone number (or number sequence) that begins with a particular single digit (multiple numbers on the same line)

Tags: regex

Newbie question but how can I check for instances where there are multiple numbers on the same line. For instance, the content reads for example contact 408-555-5454 or reach out to 408-555-4545. Right now the best I can do is ^4 but that's only catching multiple things if the mutliline flag is tured on. Any idea.

Comment: Have you tried searching online for "Phone Number Regex"? It should give you many hits, including [this one](http://phoneregex.com/) which is a great place to start for this.

Comment: I did, finally found one that worked after a few hours searching and experimenting. The setup for a particular starting digit was what was throwing me/my search off. Solved it though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the regex below

`/4\d{2}(-| )?\d{3}(-| )?\d{4}/g`

This of course assumes that you're looking for numbers that start with 4. You can have a look at the Regex Snippet [here](https://regex101.com/r/q0tOX1/2)  and you can experiment with trying different variations of the regex to suit your needs.

here's a key to the regex elements included:

1. `4` = matches the literal number 4
2. `\d{2}` = matches 2 digits (0-9).
3. `(-| )?` = matches either a hyphen or single space but makes it not required. ie you can have a space or hyphen or not.
4. `\d{3}` = matches 3 digits (0-9)
5. Same as #3 above
6. `\d{4}` = matches 4 digits (0-9)
7. the g flag will ensure that you're searching through the whole text and not stopping after the first match.

If you like the answer please Accept it :)

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for breaking it down!